# A plot with different colors and pch

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have this table:

```
structure(list(Samples = structure(1:7, .Label = c("Sample1", 
"Sample2", "sample3", "sample4", "sample5", "sample6", "sample7"
), class = "factor"), number_cycle = c(22L, 22L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
22L, 22L), Quality = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Bad", 
"Good", "Middle"), class = "factor"), Concentration = c(14L, 
24L, 22L, 40L, 10L, 27L, 12L), Raw_reads = c(100000L, 5000L, 
70000L, 340000L, 4789L, 50000L, 25000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I would like to do a scatter plot (raw_reads ~ concentration) which I can observe the dispersion of two factors: quality (colors) and number of cycles (pch). When I try this code, I have a plot without any point.

```
palette(rainbow(3))
plot(test$Raw_reads ~ test$Concentration, 
     col = test$Quality, 
     pch = test$number_cycle)
legend(x = "topleft", 
       legend = levels(test$Quality),
       col = rainbow(3), 
       pch = test$number_cycle)
```

So what can I do to obtain my scatter plot?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When I try your code, I get warnings about *"unimplemented pch value '26'"*, I think you should investigate that. (If you bring `number_cycle` down so that all of its numbers are within `0:25`, you'll see more. Try `plot(0:25, 0:25, pch=0:25)` for a demo.)

Comment: or just set `pch = as.numeric(as.factor(test$number_cycle))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use base R plot, for colors and pch,
you need to specify a vector that is as long as your datapoints. For pch, you need to specify valid numbers 1:20 i think and for colours, either a factor, or characters. One way to get around is to call out a predefined pch or col vector:

```
palette(rainbow(3))
PCH = c(18,19)
names(PCH) = as.character(unique(test$number_cycle))
COL = palette(rainbow(3))
names(COL) = unique(test$Quality)
plot(test$Raw_reads,test$Concentration, 
col = COL[test$Quality], pch = PCH[as.character(test$number_cycle)])
legend(x = "topleft", legend = names(COL), fill = COL)
legend(x = 80000,y=42, legend = names(PCH), col = "black",pch = PCH)
```

You also need two legends, one for color, one for pch.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much StupidWolf for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! Have fun with your sequencing data :)